# Web Logic, JAVA, T3: no initial context exception

Tags: java, weblogic12c

im getting this error i don't know whats missing in my code i'm new in web logic.. any help would be appreciated

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.rest.client.Type4Conn.main(Type4Conn.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my Code

```
Properties p=new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://http://192.168.1.188:7001/jdbcDataSource");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

InitialContext ctx=new InitialContext(p);

DataSource ds=(DataSource)ctx.lookup("ds_orclmrcos");  
Connection con=ds.getConnection();
Statement st=con.createStatement();

int a=st.executeUpdate("insert into user values('test','testuser',2)");
System.out.println(a+" records inserted");
```

this [link](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/04/how-to-use-datasource-from-weblogic-how.html) is my reference..

Comment: Your link says "To run this program, you have to put weblogic.jar file into class-path otherwise it will create run-time problem." - do you have done so?

Comment: actually i already have my weblogic.jar file.. and im also thinking about that point.. and im doubtful if i have the correct weblogic jar file.. where can i get the weblogic jar file..

Comment: [these guys](https://forums.oracle.com/message/2703482) say it's in `$WL_HOME/server/lib`

Comment: im using 32bit client and my server is in 64bit, is this affect my error?

Comment: how can i access that location.. im sorry maybe its a lame to ask but im new here..

Comment: Sounds unlikely. Your exception indicates you don't have the classpath set to something that includes the weblogic.jar (or something that contains the `WLInitialContextFactory`) at all.